# Database connection to remote machine in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-connection

Here is strange problem.

databse server ip : 170.2.14.131

application server ip : 170.2.14.137

Application is on cloud server. Database server is on another instance
and application hosted on different instance.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: database_name
  username: ************
  password: ************
  host: 170.2.14.131
```

This is my database.yml configuration for production environment.

Now when i am  trying to connect through my application it's using
application server IP instead of remote databse IP.

Please suggest.

Comment: Just to clarify `development` is the correct environment?  Just stands out as I wouldn't expect development to be running on separate machines in the cloud.

Comment: In production we are not getting log, but we are getting same error also for production environment.

Comment: What makes you say that it's connecting to the wrong server? What precise error messages/exceptions are you seeing?

Comment: Overcome issue by setting Mysql privileges . Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL database server remote access disabled for security reasons. there're 3 solutions to this problem, i'll not describe them here, you can read about it in my blog here: 
http://notes.kloop.kg/2011/11/17/enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server/

Comment: Overcome issue by setting Mysql privileges , thanks for all support.